# Inherit tableview cell deque error in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableview cell and its .xib called **BaseTableviewCell** in which I have defined the outlets for the components like labels, buttons etc. I have another class called **CustomTableviewCell** which inherits the **BaseTableviewCell** and it performs various actions on the outlets defined in the base.

*My question is how do I register and deque **CustomTableviewCell** in my tableview controller.*

I used the below which is not working correctly and leading to application crash

```
tableview.register(UINib(nibName: "BaseTableviewCell",
                                       bundle: nil ),
                                 forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomTableviewCell")
```

In cellForRowAt I wrote the following

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableviewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableviewCell
    return cell
}
```

Please help me as to where I am going wrong and fix this issues

Comment: I guess registering CustomTableviewCell instead of BaseTableviewCell is something you already tried, and you double checked your .xib name, right?

Comment: @SavcaMarin Yes I already did as in the code snippet